# MSP430 RAM protection

Tags: msp430, ram, register

I'm looking at the user guide for the MSP430x5xx family. It says there in section 9.1 that:

```
The RCCTL0 register is protected with a key. Only if the correct key is
written during a word write, the RCCTL0 register content can be modified.   
Byte write accesses or write accesses with a wrong key are ignored.
```

And in section 9.3.1 that:

```
Field RCKEY: RAM controller key. Always read as 69h. Must be written as
5Ah, otherwise the RAMCTL write is ignored.
```

1. Can anyone explain to me what a strange protection if the password (code) 5Ah is known? For what purpose it was made?
2. Why RCKEY always read as 69h (not 5Ah)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me what a strange protection if the password(code) 5Ah is known?

It protects you from random modification by runaway code, e.g. on stack overflow.

> Why RCKEY always read as 69h(not 5Ah)?

So you cannot simply read->write it - part of the protection mentioned above.

Microcontroller code often contains code that read-modify-writes a memory location to set or clear some bit. With the values 69h and 5Ah it is highly unlikely that such code path triggers a sucessful write in a runaway case.